# Defining states for a FSM with n states. (java)

Tags: java, enums, state

I have never worked with enum State before and recently came across it, I've found that to define a FSM where YOU, the programmer, knows the states the code is something like this:

> enum States {state0, state1, state2}; //an example of a state machine with 3 states as defined by the programmer.

but I want to be able to define a FSM where the user decides how many and what states there are, is there a way to do this?

Comment: You'd only use enums when you know how many states there will be. You *could* create some kind of `StateMachineBuilder`, which accepts states and a transition tables, but that could get a bit complex as you decouple. If I were you, I'd create some kind of `TransitionTable` class which you add states to, then specify the transitions between the states, which you could then add to some universal Finite State Machine that works based off the transition table. Thats just my opinion though

Comment: I have a transition table (stored as a 2D arraylist with Strings) where I can add rows+columns (states) and cell nxm would be where I store the transition labels, I have a bunch of add/get/set methods for this table too. I'm having trouble turning this into a state machine. :/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use enums here, which have a fixed size, but I guess you can do something like this :

```
public class StateMachine {
    // it is up to you to define what a State and a Transition are
    private Set<State> possibleStates;
    private Set<Transition> transitions;
    private State currentState;

    // methods for adding and removing states
    // ...

    // methods for adding and removing transitions
    // ...    
}
```

Comment: I tried to do possibleStates.add(); but it doesn't seem to work...?

Comment: Unclear, what exactly didn't work ? Calling a method on a `Set` is not so hard...

Comment: Sorry, first time working with Sets and State. Are sets like Lists? What type of thing should I put in the .add method parameter? State.NEW?

Comment: Look at the documentation. In a `Set<T>`, you are supposed to add `T` values. However, if the user can define states himself, it is very unlikely that you are going to write something like `State.NEW` (that would be an enum, known at compile-time). `State` will typically wrap some `String` or other type describing the current state

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no great way to make run-time enums. There are, however a few other options:

1. Use an int to represent your state. This is simple and efficient, but can be confusing and difficult to understand later, as an int doesn't tell you much about what the state means. This can be partially mitigated by storing a map from Integer(state) to String (description of that state)
2. Create an immutable class to represent a state, or wrap an existing one like String. Make instances of the class only available through a static factory method which restricts the states given out to the subset you need, and internally keep a set of all instances, providing them when the same state is asked for twice from the factory method.This will allow equality comparison by reference, and creates similar semantics to enums.

There is the separate problem (which arises on both options) of deciding on action based on state, because the state is only defined at runtime, you cannot use a switch statement. A linear search, equivalent to chained if statements, scales poorly with the number of states. This problem can be solved by creating a hash table (or binary tree, if you wish) from states to whatever code you want to execute: (Java 8)

```
HashMap<State, Function<State, State> stateTransitions;
```

This system provides enum-like semantics at runtime, with reasonably good (constant time "switch") efficiency.